# How to simulate a socket error

Tags: sockets, delphi

I have created a test server program in Delphi by using TIdTCPServer that simulates multiple servers on the same PC by adding multiple ports to the bindings by the call IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Add. This works well.

But I also want to simulate a network unplugged error for a port that should return a socket error to the client. I tried Bindings.Delete for that port and also tried CloseSocket but without success. Any ideas on how to simulate that error by disabling or deleting a port?

Comment: I suppose you could free the server component, but that's a rather dirty way to do it.

Comment: You can cause a read timeout by not sending anything, and you can cause a connection reset by setting SO_LINGER on with zero timeout and closing the socket, but you can't simulate a cable pull or router outage.

Comment: Set a firewall rule to block a port or ip address range when you want to simulate loss of network or lost of connectivity.

Comment: Often the OS will "protect" you, so that simulating a network error on a single machine is a close to impossible headache... BUT, using a VM, you can easily do it - kill the VM with no warning (Power Off the virtual machine) and a network error occurs... alternatively, implement a user land TCP/IP protocol over a raw socket, circumventing the OS kernel layer... a VM is easier.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this as a comment, but now that I think of it, I beleive this is the "best approach" answer (although maybe not what you were hoping for):

The OS will "protect" you, so that simulating a network error on a single machine is a close to impossible headache.

BUT, using a VM (virtual machine), you can easily do it - use the VM as a "client" to connect to your server application and then kill the VM with no warning (Power Off the virtual machine) - voilà a network error occurs.

Alternatively, implement a user land TCP/IP protocol over a raw socket, circumventing the OS kernel layer... a VM is easier.

Comment: I made this program specifically to avoid running different machines/VMs in order to test the multi-client work flow. I will explore other options before I go the VM way. Thanks.